# C# Serial Port Receive Only Ever Giving me a Single Character

Tags: c#, serial-port

**Question Withdrawn.  I found out that I was sending incorrect ASCII patterns and THIS was my problem versus any problems with the receiver.  Receiving a single character was merely the echo back of my wrong command**

Summary:
C# form app.  Serial 38400:N81 no flow control.  Talking to a custom device.

If I use Teraterm, everything's fine.

The device I attach to gives simple, immediate responses:

Type 'v' you get a version string "v1.34  02-18-16  17:22" where the v in that is the local echo of the typed command.  There are other status commands which are similar, once a character is received by the device, it replies immediately.

In my C# application I have pretty much exactly what you see in this guide under the example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Differences are that I'm at 38400 versus 9600 and I also do not set up the Handshake or the RtsEnable.

I've done this before so feeling stupid as to some obvious problem here.  And I did do a bit of searching/following similar question links too.

Instead of receiving the version string, I receive one character '6'.

For a different command I also receive one character '8'.  The notable thing here is that while '6' is part of my version string, '8' is never in the response for that other command.

Any suggestions on how I'd debug the ReadExisting() call?

I fully understand that a received string may arrive in fragments.  The issue is that I always only ever receive the one character and nothing else.  The event handler never sees any additional data.  When I re-issue my version command I get the same '6' back I get before.

My event handler where I'm trying to test the receiver:

```
    private void ReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Debug.WriteLine("Data Received: ");
        Debug.Write(indata);
    }
```

Under the debugger, indata.Length is 1.

Teraterm Port Settings:

[image: Teraterm port settings]

I was suggested to look for errors and here's the code:

```
    public event SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler ErrorReached;

    protected virtual void OnReceiveError(SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler handler = ErrorReached;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Serial error");
    }
```

I saw no errors.

Further comments were that the receiver needs to be run more than once.  It is, when I issue a 'v' (just the v) I should see the version and 's' should give me status.  Again, both work fine on Teraterm.  I get 686868 if I issue vsvsvs or other matching patterns if I type like vvsss, I'll get 66888 in reply.

Other point is controlling this device if I issue r and s for run and stop, there is a LED on it which goes solid red (from intermittent flashing to indicate that it's running.  I see it run and stop per my commands.  So I know that I'm talking to the device in a proper/coherent fashion.  Just still have troubles seeing valid receive data.

Comment: DO you know that ReceiveData can be executed more than once and on each call you can receive a part of what the device sent?

Comment: That's entirely normal, serial ports are slow and modern machines are very fast.  Don't interpret received data until you got *all* of it.  Usually trivially done by calling ReadLine() instead, depends.

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Trying checking for errors.  Having difficulty due to my inexperience.  The SerialDataReceiveEventHandler should be called every time there's data on the port.  I've use that before at 230400 bps and not lost data.  Slow, sure, but at 38400 that's 1/4 mSec per character, so even my version string there is about 4-5 mSec total duration.  Note that I also receive following data (8) when I try my next status command and then re-receive the 6 again when I re-try the version command.  I do not think there's any problem with the performance of the receiving routine.

Comment: I updated the problem description because added code in that appears properly.

Comment: An update is that I feel there is something wrong with how the port is configured in spite of nothing evident.  I've measured the output of the UART on the device when using TeraTerm and I see clear 38400 bps, multiple characters.  When using my application, I see one character ... sort of.  The clocking of the bits is incorrect.  This should not be, and the only difference is TeraTerm versus my application.  So my guess is that some port setting is incorrect that I haven't noticed.  I shall pore through the entire scope of port settings.

Comment: Final update is per my comment somewhere in the middle of my question.    Yes, I AM stupid, I misread the ASCII representation of some characters and thus I was sending 0x36 as opposed to 0x56 and instead of sending 'V' I was sending '6' and the device was merely echoing my incorrect command back to me.  Sorry, knew it had to be simple - I'll withdraw the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions to try:

You're reading a string from the port, so if the data can't be readily interpreted as a string you may only get a fragment before it stops converting. Read into a byte array to be sure you are really seeing the data that you receive. Even if you think you should get a string, this lets you see what you are actually receiving.

Check your port settings. Symptoms of the wrong baud rate or encoding are frequently that you receive a reduced number of (possibly random, possibly repeatable) bytes of "garbage". This would be consistent with receiving characters that should not be in the response, and the string terminating early.

Remove all configuration options from your port, apart from setting the baud rate. Very few devices use anything other than 8n1 and attempting to set options can often screw the port up. If that doesn't work then start seeing additional options only if you have to.

Make sure you only open the port once and keep it open till you have finished talking to the device. (Repeatedly opening and closing the port I'd really five by accident, and would flush the data in it, interfering with your attempts to read)